# Proof that a regular expression is not a regular language using pumping lemma

Tags: regular-language, dfa, pumping-lemma

Ok, I know that this isn't a programming question but it is a computing question so it is relevant.

Basically, how can I use the pumping lemma to prove that this language is not regular?

{w in {0,1}* | if the length of w is odd then the middle symbol is 0}

Please answer this as simple as possible as whilst I know about models of computation, I am relatively new to it.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @templatetypedef I haven't been able to try anything so far. I know what the pumping lemma is but I don't know how to apply it to this situation

Comment: "regular-expression is not a regular language" - well this is not possible regular expression can only be written for a regular language. Regular expression is a proof that certain language *is a* regular language.

Answer (score 0):

According to the pumping lemma, if that language is regular then there must exist a number *p* such that for all strings longer than *p* in the language, we can decompose that string into *x* + *y* + *z*, where each of *x*, *y*, and *z* are strings and |*y*| >= 1, |*x* + *y*| <= *p*, and *x* + (*y* * *i*) + *z* is in the language for all non-negative integers *i*.

Now observe that for every non-negative integer *i*, the string "`1`" * *i* + "`0`" + "`1`" * *i* is in the language. (That is, the string of *i* `1`s followed by a single `0` and then *i* more `1`s)

Specifically, the string *S* consisting of *p* `1`s followed by a `0` and then *p* more `1`s is in the language. Since this string has length 2 *p* + 1, this string is long enough that it can be broken into three strings *x*, *y*, and *z* as in the pumping lemma. Since |*x* + *y*| <= *p*, it must be that *x* and *y* are all `1`s, and the only `0` character in *S* is in *z*. Now consider the string *S'* = *x* + *y* + *y* + *y* + *z*. Since we added 2*|*y*| characters to it, *S'* must also have an odd length. But we added some number of `1` characters to the left of the only `0` in *S*, and didn't add any `1` characters to the right of the `0`. So *S'* doesn't have a `0` as its middle character, and therefore *S'* isn't in the language.

Therefore, we've shown that the language can't be pumped as the pumping lemma requires. Therefore, the language is not regular.